# Error while converting ui file to py file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, command-prompt, qt-designer

This is my first time using python and when I was trying to convert a ui file into a python file, it is showing this error again and again. Unable to figure out the problem.

```
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Python36\Scripts>pyuic5 -x myui.ui -o myui.py

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
```

Comment: "myui.ui" is in folder "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Python36\Scripts"?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes...that's why I am not understanding what the problem is...

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried to move the file to desktop and then try the same thing and then it shows this:   C:\Users\myusername\Desktop>pyuic5 -x myui.ui -o myui.py
'pyuic5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @eyllanesc I even tried using pyuic.exe, it gives the same message